# React setting state from an axios response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am attempting to update state with information returned from an axios POST call.  I am getting an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`.  It sounds to me like `this` is not usable from a API response.

```
submitData= () => {
        axios.post("url", this.props.data)
        .then(function (result) {
            console.log(result,'success');
            this.setState({
                ...this.state,
                id: result.data.id
            })
          })
          .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err, 'fail');
          });

    }
```

I can console log `result.data.id` and it is the correct id.  I am doing this all client side and I do not want to build out a server or use a reducer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use arrow function in your callback like this :

```
submitData= () => {
        axios.post("url", this.props.data)
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result,'success');
            this.setState({
                ...this.state,
                id: result.data.id
            })
          })
          .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err, 'fail');
          });

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use async/await syntax and pass data as argument for greater flexibility/reusability. Try:

```
submitData = async (data) => {
    try {
        const result = await axios.post('url', data);
        console.log('Success', result);
        const { id } = result.data;
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            id,
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Failure', err);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making the `.then` an anonymous function to bind `this`.

```
submitData= () => {
    axios.post("url", this.props.data)
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result,'success');
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            id: result.data.id
        })
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err, 'fail');
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the callback function `this` would be undefined (that's how `this` in js works).
If you want an easy fix, just use arrow functions

```
submitData= () => {
        axios.post("url", this.props.data)
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result,'success');
            this.setState({
                ...this.state,
                id: result.data.id
            })
          })
          .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err, 'fail');
          });
    }
```

read more about `this` https://hackernoon.com/javascript-es6-arrow-functions-and-lexical-this-f2a3e2a5e8c4